# Push notifications to browser window

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, node.js

I am hosting my own server on my private Windows 8 machine.

I am looking to develop an online chat application as a part of a larger website i am developing. A simple Google search suggested using AJAX requests and a server-side chat HTML page, with the browser sending requests to fetch the page every so often via a Javascript loop. I didn't really like this approach, and was looking for something a little more "modern". Normal chat programs use push notifications, so i figured i should be able, too. Maybe something like this would work:

- Server-side program/script listens on a port for incoming requests.
- Browser sends an AJAX request to the server on the specified port whenever a user types in a message.
- Server-side program/script records the message in a MySQL database or file.
- Server sends a ... something ... to the browser window.
- Client web page receives the something from the server (via JS?) and formats/displays the message appropriately.

I have only had experience with static pages (HTML/CSS/JS) in the past, and have just recently dabbled in PHP. So ... i naturally have some questions.

- What port should i use? Do i just pick a number and stick with it, or are there specific numbers that are meant for specific things?
- Can i write the server-side program in C/C++? I am pretty sure i could download and learn to use libraries that would interact with MySQL databases and send requests. Should i use another language? Would it be easier in a scripting language like Python?
- The big one: How on earth am i going to receive the request on the client side? I don't know of any sort of JavaScript push notification API.

I tried using NodeJS, but i have no idea if that would be suitable for my needs, or if there are better alternatives. To be honest i don't really even know what it is...

Answer (score 1):

I would say stick with Node combined with socket.io.  You can create a push notification application pretty quickly with these.

Check out the socket.io site: http://socket.io

Also, I really should have mentioned Sails.  It's an MVC framework for Node that has socketio built right in.

http://sailsjs.org/#/

Comment: This is pretty nice. I will take a more detailed look. Thanks :D